# How to write a R loop to add multiple excel files, change their column names, and then combine them based on one row?

Tags: r, excel, loops

Beginner here, I have 31 excel files that I want to extract the data frame. I want a R loop to read all the files, then only take 2 columns and change the column names. Then I want to combine the files based on the same row.

[image]

This is my attempt:

```
files = list.files(path=".", pattern="xls")
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  table = data.frame(readxl::read_xls(files[i]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  table = table[,c(1,3)]
  colnames(table) = c("UR",paste0("Zscore",i))
    } 
  }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know to code it to save the individual file. This code only saves the last file. I tried googling all night and couldn't figure it out.
I also tried assign() but I don't know how to modify the tables within assign as part of the loop.

```
files = list.files(pattern="*.xls")
for (i in 1:length(files))assign(files[i], data.frame(readxl::read_xls(files[i])))
```

I want to files to end up like UR, Zscore1, Zscore2, Zscore3...
[image]

```
So instead I did it manually like this:
table1 = data.frame(readxl::read_xls(files[1]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
table1 = table1[,c(1,3)]
colnames(table1) = c("UR",paste0("Zscore",1))


table2 = data.frame(readxl::read_xls(files[2]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
table2 = table2[,c(1,3)]
colnames(table2) = c("UR",paste0("Zscore",2))
tableA = merge(table1,table2, all.x = T)


table3 = data.frame(readxl::read_xls(files[3]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
table3 = table3[,c(1,3)]
colnames(table3) = c("UR",paste0("Zscore",3))
tableA = merge(tableA,table3, all.x = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach with `lapply` and `Reduce` :

```
files = list.files(path=".", pattern="xls")

Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all.x = T, by = 'UR'), 
        lapply(seq_along(files), function(i) {
              data <- readxl::read_xls(files[i])
              data <- data[c(1, 3)]
              names(data) <- c('UR', paste0('Zscore', i))
              data
})) -> result

result
```

Comment: I tried your code. But got the Error in merge.data.frame(x, y, all.x = T, by = "UR") : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed

Comment: I got the code to work be removing all.x=T. Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you are not assigning the table to anything, so you are rebuilding the table on every iteration.

For every iteration, you should assign the created table as a corresponding element [[i]] of either a data frame or a list, using the assign operator <-

Maybe something like this will work:

```
files <- list.files(path=".", pattern="xls")
list_of_tables<-vector(mode = "list", length = (length(files))

for (i in seq_along(files)){
  list_of_tables[i] <- data.frame(readxl::read_xls(files[i]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[,c(1,3)]
  names(list_of_tables[i]) <- c("UR",paste0("Zscore",i))
}
```

Then, if you want to stack the whole list in a single data frame, you can use cbind, as in:

```
my_data_frame<-do.call(cbind, list_of_tables)
```

Otherwise just keep it as a list

Comment: I tried running your code. But it keeps saying "Error: path does not exist: ‘NA’." Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Just edited the for loop, maybe it works now

Comment: If you it says  "Error: path does not exists" make sure you have the right path of your files in `list.files(path="here_your_files_path", pattern="xls")`

Comment: I have the correct path because I'm able to get the list of files names from the first line.  Now It's giving me Error "In list_of_tables[i] <- data.frame(readxl::read_xls(files[i]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[,c(1,3)] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: The empty list was created as a list with only one element. Corrected.

Comment: Still has the same error In list_of_tables[i] <- data.frame(readxl::read_xls(files[i]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[,c(1,3)] : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length